# AddThresholdColorRule giving error Spotfire (Iron Python)

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.ConditionalColoring import *
from System.Drawing import Color

# Get the visualization reference
for visualization in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
  if visualization.Title == "Test Bar Chart1":
    visualContentObject = visualization.As[VisualContent]()

#Clear default coloring
visualContentObject.ColorAxis.Coloring.Clear()
#set color
visualContentObject.ColorAxis.Coloring.AddThresholdColorRule(StringComparisonOperator.GreaterOrEqual, ConditionValue.CreateLiteral('40'), Color.FromName("Green"))
```

I have a string column in Value Axis which I want to conditionally color green for values greaterorequal than 40.I  have tried this code but it gives an error no attribute named GreaterOrEqual

The script parameters that I have defined are visualization and visualContentObject both of them point to the bar chart in the visualization

Answer (score 2):

you have written:

```
StringComparisonOperator.GreaterOrEqual
```

you should have written:

```
RuleComparisonOperator.GreaterOrEqual
```

:)

source: [API docs](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire-analyst_api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_ConditionalColoring_RuleComparisonOperator.htm)

Comment: just wanted to add, it's cases like this that make me lean towards never importing `*`. rather, I prefer to specify each class that I'll need in the code. had you done it this way, you would have had an easier time spotting this typo.

Comment: The error is removed but the conditional color formatting that I have implemented in the script for the Bar Chart visualization is not applied after execution of script,Plz help.

Comment: Plz tell where am I doing wrong?Why can't I see the color changes on bar chart while script execution.